# Angular Autocomplete - how to defer API request for data until user focuses the field?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working with Angular Material Autocomplete in a project for getting a list of sites which could be quite large (thousands of rows).

I know that `startWith` is triggering the initial load of 100% of records (unfiltered), and I hope to remove `startWith` once I figure out a better way.

The problem is: this form has many filters, and I do not want to download data unless the filter is used. So I don't want all the fields to start hitting the API at once. I want to wait to download the data (whether filtered or not) until the user actually focuses or touches/clicks the input. What's the right way to do this with angular? I've goofed around with triggering the `nativeElement.focus`, but I'm kind of stuck. Any advice? Thanks!

```
this.sites$ = this.filterGroup.get('site').valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(''),
    debounceTime(400),
    switchMap(val => {
      return this.getSites(val)
    })
```

Comment: So don't know how to listen to the `focus` event? Or you don't know how to trigger the chain on `focus` event?

Comment: I don't think `ngrx` tag has anything to do with the question, also i'd guess `delayWhen` is the operator you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a subject to trigger your fetching:

```js
private fetchSites$ = new Subject<void>();

public sites$ = this.fetchSites$.pipe(
  startWith([]),
  switchMap(() => filterGroup.get('site').valueChanges),
  debounceTime(400),
  switchMap(val => this.getSites(val))
);

public fetchSites() {
  this.fetchSites$.next();
}
```

Then, in your template, you could trigger the `fetchSites$.next()` on the `(focus)` event:

```js
    <input 
      [formControl]="myControl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      (focus)="fetchSites()"
    >

    <mat-autocomplete #auto>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of sites$ | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this to track when the element was "blurred", meaning it lost focus:

```js
  @ViewChildren(FormControlName, { read: ElementRef }) formInputElements: ElementRef[];

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Watch for the blur event from any input element on the form.
    // This is required because the valueChanges does not provide notification on blur
    const controlBlurs: Observable<any>[] = this.formInputElements
      .map((formControl: ElementRef) => fromEvent(formControl.nativeElement, 'blur'));

    // Merge the blur event observable with the valueChanges observable
    // so we only need to subscribe once.
    merge(this.productForm.valueChanges, ...controlBlurs).pipe(
      debounceTime(800)
    ).subscribe(value => {
      this.displayMessage = this.genericValidator.processMessages(this.productForm);
    });
  }
```

Is this what you are asking about?